# Flickr api not fetching images using React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, flickr, axios

I am trying to fetch a list of images from tags but nothing is being console logged or rendering out. Not sure If I am missing a parameter with the api.

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWgBgd?editors=0010

```
const url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=kitten&format=json"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.jsonFlickrFeed.items);
            this.setState({
                items: response.data.jsonFlickrFeed.items
            })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      })
  }

  render() {
        const mappedStorage = this.state.items.map((item) => <li>{item.media.m} </li>)

    return (
      <div>
       hello
                <ul>{mappedStorage}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

Comment: are you seeing any CORS warnings in your console? have you tried console logging the response to see what that returns

Comment: I was able to use this same code and get it working but i had to use this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en since you are using the client to make the api call you need to make sure that you are allowing cross-origin resource sharing. Browsers normally don't allow this but their are plugin work arounds. The best way is to have a backend server that makes the request and then sends it back to the front end and front end only communicates with back end thats same origin

Comment: I have the extension installed already. Here is a codepen. Still no dice.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWgBgd?editors=0010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, Flickr does some weird stuff with their api unless you pass in the right stuff. Set the url to:

`http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=kitten&format=json&nojsoncallback=true`

and then update code to be

```
axios.get("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=kitten&format=json&nojsoncallback=true") 
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.items);
    this.setState({
        items: response.data.items
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
  })
```

seems the main thing is if you dont add `nojsoncallback=true` the JSON they return is a callback function which isn't parsable by normal means luckily they give you a param to return what you want.

working pen http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/WRWgPw?editors=0011

Comment: That is not working anymore, check the codepen, console throws Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Comment: @TomaszNowak the original poster was using a extension to get around CORS so this answer was targeted at them. You would need to download something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en and have it turned on to get around the CORS issue, or use a server to send the request vs the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your axios call is failing:

```
.catch((err) => {
        debugger;
            console.log(err);
  })

Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (VM970 axios.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (VM970 axios.min.js:2)
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I have a cors chrome extension installed, that will allow cross headers